# Jstree: How can i avoid to check disabled checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a tree in which few of the nodes are disabled.If the parent is enabled and few of its child are in disabled state and i try to check the parent node then all the nodes are checked.I want only nodes which are enabled should be checked.

```
$('#Tree').jstree({
    plugins: ["themes","checkbox","json_data","ui","types","real_checkboxes"],
    "checkbox" : {
        "keep_selected_style" : false,
        "tie_selection" : false,
        "three_state" : true,
        "real_checkboxes" : true
    },
    "core":
    {
        "themes": {
            "icons": false
        },
        "data":Products
    },
    "types":{
        "types":{
            "disabled" : {
                "check_node" : false,
                "uncheck_node" : false,
                "select_node": false,
                "open_node":   false,
                "close_node":  false,
                "create_node": false,
                "delete_node": false
            } ,
            "directory" : {

                "check_node" : false,
                "uncheck_node" : false
            },
            "default" : { 
                "check_node" : function () { 
                    if(node_should_be_disabled) return false; 
                    return true; 
                }, 
                "uncheck_node" : function () { 
                    if(node_should_be_disabled) return false; 
                    return true; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
           $('.altGrup').jstree({
                "checkbox": {
                    three_state: false
                },
                "plugins": ["checkbox"]
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide an example in jsFiddle ?